# HP Pavilion dv4-2145dx operating system

Tags: windows-7

I have the above laptop. I got it without a hard drive. The COA key is clearly visible but the actual operating system that goes to that key is missing...rubbed off. What operating system came with this particular machine? Thanks

Comment: Please do some [research](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv4-2145dx/4505-3121_7-33970189.html) on topics before coming to SU to ask questions.  We tend to expect that you have done some leg work up front and ask based on where you are stuck rather than expecting others to do the work for you.  (On that link, hit `Ctrl+F` and search for "Windows" - it will tell you the version).

Comment: We will be unable to tell you this information. The most likely answer is `Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium` you can verify this by trying to install it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the HP Pavilion dv4-2145dx came with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, according to the [CNET review](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv4-2145dx/4505-3121_7-33970189.html).  This does not *necessarily* mean the computer came with that particular operating system, as it *is* possible to request a different Operating System when purchasing a computer from HP.  Still, I'd put your percent chance of Windows 7 Home Premium being the correct Operating System for that product key to be in the high 90's.

There [is not an easy way](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_install/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-version-of-a/f60a591d-22ab-47c3-92de-266b30b5bf00) to determine with 100% accuracy which Operating System a product key belongs to.

Another option is purchasing a restore disk for that model of computer.  I've used [restoredisks.com](http://www.restoredisks.com/) several times for various HP laptops I've owned when hard drives have failed.  For $26.99, they will send you a disk or set of disks including the operating system and any drivers that were shipped with that computer based on the model number.

Comment: Yup it is the cheapest way to get a legit copy. I have not used restoredisks.com, only the manufacturers website when needed. Its good to read about a new source.